# Docker multiple MYSQL containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker newbie here.

What I'm trying to achieve is to run multiple MySQL containers with docker compose, in addition to an nginx, a PHP and a PhpMyAdmin container.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    server:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: server.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        links:
            - app
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        links:
            - db_callcenter
            - db_forecast
            - db_logistics
            - db_products
            - db_rm
            - db_rma
            - db_settings
            - db_tasks
            - db_users
    db_callcenter:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=prj_callcenter"
        ports:
            - "33061:3306"
        volumes:
            - mysql_bkp:/var/lib/mysql
    db_forecast:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=prj_forecast"
        ports:
            - "33062:3306"
        volumes:
            - mysql_bkp:/var/lib/mysql
    db_logistics:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=prj_logistics"
        ports:
            - "33063:3306"
        volumes:
            - mysql_bkp:/var/lib/mysql
    db_products:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=prj_products"
        ports:
            - "33064:3306"
        volumes:
            - mysql_bkp:/var/lib/mysql
    db_rm:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=prj_rm"
        ports:
            - "33065:3306"
        volumes:
            - mysql_bkp:/var/lib/mysql
    db_rma:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=prj_rma"
        ports:
            - "33066:3306"
        volumes:
            - mysql_bkp:/var/lib/mysql
    db_settings:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=prj_settings"
        ports:
            - "33067:3306"
        volumes:
            - mysql_bkp:/var/lib/mysql
    db_tasks:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=prj_tasks"
        ports:
            - "33068:3306"
        volumes:
            - mysql_bkp:/var/lib/mysql
    db_users:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=prj_users"
        ports:
            - "33069:3306"
        volumes:
            - mysql_bkp:/var/lib/mysql
    pma:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        environment:
            - "PMA_USER=root"
            - "PMA_PASSWORD=secret"
        ports:
            - "8001:80"
        links:
            - db_callcenter
            - db_forecast
            - db_logistics
            - db_products
            - db_rm
            - db_rma
            - db_settings
            - db_tasks
            - db_users
volumes:
    mysql_bkp:
```

But none of the MySQL containers are created. When I run docker ps I get:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
0228e9c8a267        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/run.sh phpmyadmin"     About a minute ago   Up 30 seconds       0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp   prj_pma_1
e6c6b11905f1        prj_server             "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   22 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   prj_server_1
2e7dd484c6e5        prj_app                "docker-php-entryp..."   24 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        9000/tcp               prj_app_1
```

UPDATE:

docker logs shows:

```
Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
```

or

```
InnoDB: Unsupported redo log format.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or how I should start debugging. Any help would be mostly appreciated.

Comment: What does `docker ps -a` show you?

Comment: Are you running `docker-compose up` to start everything? Can you change each instance of `links` to `depends_on` so it starts the database containers first? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on

Comment: @frennky

docker ps -a show the db containers with, but with a status of Exited (1) 15 hours

Comment: And what does `docker logs <db  container id>` show you? Can you add one of those logs to your original question?

Comment: @frennky

It varies, but it usually is:

InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
or
InnoDB: Unsupported redo log format. (...)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't have multiple mysql processes sharing the same data directory.  In your compose file, every database container is using the same `mysql_bkp` volume.  You will need to either create one volume per container, or configure mysql to use a unique *subdirectory* of `/var/lib/mysql` for storing data.

If you simply remove the `volumes:` key from each database service, they will all get a unique anonymous volume (because that's how the `mysql` image is configured).

Alternatively, you can declare and mount a separate volume for each service:

```
services:
    db_logistics:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - mysql_bkp_logistics:/var/lib/mysql
    db_products:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - mysql_bkp_products:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    mysql_bkp_logistics:
    mysql_bkp_products:
```

Etc.

Comment: Bingo! That did it. I tried without the volumes, but that didn't work, but mounting a separate volume did. Now I only have to find out why my phpMyAdmin can't connect (it does for a single DB)

Comment: I would suggest keeping the separate volumes. The assumption being you will need that DB data later.  Or you want to move it to another container. 'docker volume ls' or  'ls -lah /var/lib/docker/volumes/'

Comment: Don't you have to configure different ports for each db then also?

Comment: You are free to use the same port in multiple containers. We are not binding these containers to either the host network namespace or to a common container namespace. From a networking perspective, each container is a separate host and is free to use the same port as other containers.

Comment: that setup results in `InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11` for me. ( docker-compose 3.8)

Comment: @Cpt.Senkfuss there are a [number of things](https://bobcares.com/blog/innodb-unable-to-lock-ibdata1-error-11/) that can cause that error. If you're trying to use a configuration like this and it's not working, consider posting a new question and include the exact compose file you're using so that we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP. multiple mysql containers, different host ports and different volumes. PMA is connecting only on the first one.

Comment: @Kreker you probably want to open a new question with details about your particular configuration.